# How to append dynamically generated ajax content to a newly added tab in jquery ui tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a table in the following form on a side-panel:

```
<table>
<tr title='term1'><td>one</td></tr>
<tr title='term2'><td>two</td></tr>
<tr title='term3'><td>three</td></tr>
<tr title='term4'><td>four</td></tr>
</table>
```

When someone clicks on a row of that column, the title of that row is passed as an argument to a function which displays the search results in the main-panel.

```
$("#content-display").on('click', 'tr', function (){      
    searchResults($(this).attr('title'));        
});
```

The title of that row is the search term used in a get request

```
function searchResults(searchTerm){    
    $.ajax({
      url: "search.php",
      data: {term: searchTerm},
      success: function(data){     
            $("#content-display").html(data);
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });     
}
```

Whenever someone clicks on a row in the table, the new search results replace the old in the `#content-display` div.

I would like to improve this functionality with jquery ui tabs so that each click on a `<tr>` element would create a new tab with those search results inside of it instead of replacing the existing search results whenever a new search is done.

How can I write the callback function to the add event so that it would append the dynamically generated content of the search query (search.php?term=dynamicString)?

Here's some sample code of callback function to the add event that adds static content:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    add: function (event, ui){
        var tab_content = "testing";
        $(ui.panel).append(tab_content);                      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

jQuery UI Tabs support adding new tabs dynamically (you already added code for this).

It provides "add" method to add new items using AJAX

So, if I do this

```
$( "#tabs").tabs("add", "filename.php", "Search Heading");
```

It will load content from "firlename.php" when we click on that tab.

Also, we can select any tab using JavaScript.

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', tab_index);
```

It will select any tab with the specified index.

In your case, I assume these two will fit nicely.

Example code will be :

```
$( "#tabs").tabs("add", "search.php?term=" + search_var, search_var);
$('#tabs').tabs('select', last_index);
```

You can try this from Google Chrome developer tools' console by going to this URL
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/manipulation.html
Just add the following code in the console.

```
$( "#tabs").tabs("add", "collapsible.html", "Collapsible"); $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Friends, please suggest better solutions if any.

Thanks.